# questions on overload of int and double

Tags: c#, overloading

i have 2 methods, intMethod and doubleMethod, they are exactly the same, except intMethod takes an int array parameter and doubleMethod takes a double array parameter.

i know i can use overload to use the same method name, however, i still end up with 2 nearly identical methods which only differs by their parameters. is there anyway i can combine intMethod and doubleMethod into 1 method?

if so, can you provide some sample code please? i can follow much better with some sample code. thanks

EDIT: people request me to post my method, and there you go:

i have an identical method, readDataDouble, which the data array is double[][]

basically this method read a CSV file and convert the data to int format. the first row is time and the first column is date.

```
    public static void readDataInt(string value, ref int[][] data, ref DateTime[] timeframe, ref DateTime[] date)
    {
        string inputFile = "D:\\temp.csv";
        string[][] temp = null;

        if (File.Exists(inputFile))
        {
            string[] proRataVolumeFile = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);
            temp = new string[proRataVolumeFile.Length][];

            for (int i = 0; i < proRataVolumeFile.Length; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = proRataVolumeFile[i].Split(',');
            }
        }

              //convert the string to int

        date = new DateTime[temp.Length - 1];
        timeframe = new DateTime[temp[0].Length - 1];
        data = new int[temp.Length - 1][];

        for (int i = 1; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i - 1] = new int[temp[i].Length - 1];

            for (int j = 1; j < temp[i].Length; j++)
            {
                if (temp[i][j].Length > 0)
                    data[i - 1][j - 1] = Convert.ToInt32(temp[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            date[i - 1] = Convert.ToDateTime(temp[i][0]);
        }

        for (int j = 1; j < temp[0].Length; j++)
        {
            timeframe[j - 1] = DateTime.Parse(temp[0][j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using generics? `method<T>(T[] array)`?

Comment: "nearly identical" != identical.  It would help if you posted the method.

Comment: We can also follow much better with some sample code :) Could you add your methods since "refactoring" is much easier if you know what you're dealing with.

Comment: no problem, please read my method at the top

Answer (score 5):

It depends a lot on what the method itself does.

If the method can be written in terms of a shared interface, such as `IComparable<T>`, you can potentially make it a [generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx):

```
void SomeMethod<T>(T[] values) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

This will be more restrictive, however, as you can only use methods or properties defined by the generic constraint(s).  It works well for things where you need to compare values or check for equality, etc, but isn't good for "general purpose math", as there is no shared interface which would work (such as a theoretical `IArithmetic<T>` interface).

Edit: In your case, you should be able to use a generic method constrained to [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) implementations:

```
public static void ReadData<T>(string value, ref T[][] data, ref DateTime[] timeframe, ref DateTime[] date) where T : IConvertible
{
```

---

Another option is to declare your method to use `dynamic` instead of a specific type:

```
dynamic SomeMethod(dynamic[] values)
{
    dynamic result = values[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; ++i)
         result = result + values[i]; // You can use normal operators now
    return result;
}
```

This will work with any type, but the checks effectively move to runtime, as it uses dynamic binding.  If you pass a type which does not work properly, you'll get runtime exceptions (instead of compile-time checking).

Comment: thanks. Question: if i declare my variable as VAR, can i get around this problem, and using only varMethod? any potential pitfall using VAR rather than an int or double? (other than slower?)

Comment: @ClaytonLeung No - "var" is just a compiler inference.  You can't use it in a parameter.  You *could* use dynamic to get around this limitation - will edit to show.

Comment: thanks, i still using .net 3.5 at the moment, when i have time, i will review this part again, also i have post my method above, feel free to have a look and see if there is any improvement you can do

Comment: @ClaytonLeung You should be able to constrain to `IConvertible`, and use `(T)Convert.ChangeType(stringValue, typeof(T));` to do the conversion (instead of `Int32.Parse`, etc): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx

Comment: @ Reed, is it faster? i have lots of Convert.toInt in my code

Comment: @ClaytonLeung Nope - it'll be similar to `Convert.ToInt32` - but you'll only need one method for Int32/Double/Single/Int64/etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), The simple Swap method can help to understand how you can pass different types to Swap method with overloading Swap.

```
static void Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs)
{
  T temp;
  temp = lhs;
  lhs = rhs;
  rhs = temp;
}
```

How you will call for int

```
 int a = 2;
 int b = 3;
 Swap<int>(ref a, ref b);
```

How you will call for double

```
 double a = 2.3;
 double b = 5.7;
 Swap<double>(ref a, ref b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics, convert your arrays to lists, and then create a generic method to process your data like this:

```
    int[] ints = {1, 2, 3 };
    List<int> listInts = ints.ToList();

    MyMethod<int>(listInts);

    private static void MyMethod<T>(List<T> genericList)
    {
        // do you work
    }
```

Comment: but then you still need to structure 2 list, List<int> and List<double>, when you do calculations later, you would have casting problems?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your example, it's fairly easy to remove most of the duplication using generics and a `Func`, this is one way;

```
    public static void ReadDataInt(string value, out int[][] data, 
                         out DateTime[] timeframe, out DateTime[] date)
    {
        ReadData(value, out data, out timeframe, out date, Convert.ToInt32);
    }

    public static void ReadDataDouble(string value, out double[][] data, 
                         out DateTime[] timeframe, out DateTime[] date)
    {
        ReadData(value, out data, out timeframe, out date, Convert.ToDouble);
    }

    private static void ReadData<T>(string value, out T[][] data, 
                          out DateTime[] timeframe, out DateTime[] date, 
                          Func<string, T> converter)
    {
        ...your method goes here with some very minor changes below.

        // Generic instead of int/double
        data = new T[temp.Length - 1][];         
        ...
        // Generic instead of int/double
        data[i - 1] = new T[temp[i].Length - 1];
        ...
        // Use a func instead of the hard coded Convert.
        if (temp[i][j].Length > 0)
            data[i - 1][j - 1] = converter(temp[i][j]);
```

Of course there are probably even more refactorings you can do, but this should solve the specific problem of the almost identical methods.

Comment: thanks, i think all the answers in here have overloaded myself. is there a "prefer" method of doing so? i am still new so all the generics and Ienumerable are new to me, i have to learn from stratch anyway.

Comment: @ClaytonLeung Seeing your example code, I updated the answer.